# Gaining Mid-level Understanding of P vs NP

Tags: reference-request, np-complete

I have a base understanding of N and NP, but I want to find some material to gain a better understanding to it. E.g. 'Mid-level', something that goes more into depth of it. Any suggestions for PhD papers to read or books for a better understanding?

Comment: And I believe you mean "P vs NP", not "N vs NP".  If this wasn't just a careless typographical error, then I would suggest that your base understanding of P and NP is not as sound as you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Sipser's classic "Introduction to the theory of computation" can give you a solid base for P vs NP and computational complexity in general.
It starts fram the basics like languages and the definition of a Turing machine and goes on to more interesting theory. 
The good with this book is that many times it skips any unnecessary formalities.

Comment: I will second this; the Sipser book is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the later chapters (4–7) of  Garey and Johnson, *Computers and Intractibility: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness*.  It is old but still good.

It discusses many of the finer points of NP-completeness, such as number problems and pseudo-polynomial-time algorithms, #P-completeness, and the reasons why no resolution of $P=NP$ should be expected soon.

Comment: The later chapters Sipser's book (_Introduction to the Theory of Computation_) are also very good; the explanation is crystal clear. I don't know if this counts as "base level" or "mid level", but I expect it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend “[Shtetl-Optimized](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/)”, the blog of Scott Aaronson, who is a computer science researcher affiliated with MIT.  For example, this recent article on [The Scientific Case for P≠NP](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=1720).